# Change .exe with hexeditor

Tags: c++, hex, hex-editors

I wrote a little program in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int input;

    std::cin >> input;

    if(input == 5){
        std::cout << "Input == 5";
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Input != 5";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have already built the program. The working program is in the `Release` folder. Now I want to change the `if` statement, without changing the C++ code. I downloaded a hex editor and opened the file. Inside the `.exe` is a lot. I googled for the problem and found this very nice image:

[image]

I searched inside the hex editor for my output `Input == 5`. I found it. When I change it to something different and execute the file, the program displays the new entered message, not the old one.

[image]

But now I want to change the structure of the code (the `if` statement). I searched for `if`, but didn't find anything. So, where is the *code section* (image)?

Comment: You need to [do some reading](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/Notes/compile.html) about how your C++ code (which is human-readable) is turned into machine code (which is not).

Comment: @Archimaredes is the c++ machine code on every machine the same?

Comment: @MyNewName: It isn't, and your question hints at the fact that this might be too much for you at this point...

Comment: @DevSolar yes. Its not that easy...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ is a high-level language. It is written in "source" (plain text, i.e. `if ( ... )`), and a compiler translates that to machine code.

Machine code is a very *different*, low-level language. For one, what C++ does with "if ... else", machine code does with a "conditional branch instruction", which is a (sequence of) specific byte values, i.e. what you see in the hex editor. The "if" no longer exists.

The specific command set, and the byte values representing those commands, differ from CPU family to CPU family.

If you are *really* interested in machine code, check out [The Art of Assembly Language Programming](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/index.html) by Randy Hyde. It has a *very* good introduction to x86 assembly and machine code.

Generally speaking, though, you won't need more than token knowledge of ASM / machine code, since the subject pops up rather seldom even on the professional level, unless you are working on operating systems and / or device drivers (and most of the time not even then).

Comment: thanks for your answer! I have some little questions. x86 is the architecture of the processor? An `assembly` is the language to communicate with the processor?

Comment: @MyNewName: Yes and no. If you're running Windows or Linux on a desktop, you're likely using a [x86_64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) CPU, which is a 64-bit evolution of the (32-bit) [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86). [Assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) is an *almost*-like-machine-code intermediary with some commodity features, but as close as you get to joining "machine code" and "human readable". (Back in the *really* early days, and I'm talking the 1960's here, people *actually* wrote machine code directly. Nobody does anymore, not in earnest.)

Comment: @MyNewName: (continued) There are tools called *disassemblers*, which turn machine code back into assembly. (`objdump -D` for the GNU / Linux toolchain, don't know about Microsoft tools for that purpose.) Also useful is a compiler feature which turns your *source* into assembly. (That would be `-S` for GNU CC, again I don't know how to do that on MS Visual.) This latter way is usually more exact, since some things that end up in the binary are *not* machine code, but are interpreted as such by the disassembler, giving somewhat confusing output -- the compiler knows better what is what.

Comment: wow! Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @MyNewName: I never forgot the amount of confusion **I** was facing all those years ago when I wanted to learn... because there was no WWW yet to learn from. (Yes, it's been *that* long.) That's why I like helping newbies find their directions -- I had to learn many of these things the hard way.

Answer (score 7):

You will not find an `if` statement in your executable because it will have been translated to machine language, which is the entire purpose of the compilation process -> to translate your C++ code to something that the machine knows how to execute.

If you want to 'hack' your .exe, what you need is a disassembler and the knowledge to use it, and that is a long story, which is why your question is probably too broad for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score -7):

In c or c++ language the if statement is the same so there is nothing that you can get you a ***special if statement*** for c++.

And also when you built your program it is converted into machine level language so u can't find anything behind program. it directly shows u output